# How to filter resource in Maven, replacing with a dependencies artifactId?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, filtering, resources

I'm trying to build a jar that has an xml file as a resource.  I'd like to apply a filter to that xml to insert the name of a dependency into the xml.  The filtering is working, because I was able to drop in `${project.build.finalName}` and get it replaced.  I found [one hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234124/maven-project-variables-for-dependencies) that the property I'm looking for might be

```
${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm looking to replace

```
<fileName>${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}</fileName>
```

with

```
<fileName>OtherLibrary</fileName>
```

Is that possible?

xml, which is in src/main/resources:

```
<somenode>
  <fileName>${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}</fileName>
</somenode>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>Thing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Thing</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pts</groupId>
        <artifactId>OtherLibrary</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: This is maven 2.2.1 by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damn, you're right, this property doesn't get replaced during the filtering of resources. That's weird and it sounds like a bug in the [Maven Resources Plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES) because this property is correctly interpolated during the `process-resources` phase as I'll demonstrate in the workaround I'm suggesting below (based on the maven-antrun-plugin and the [`replace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task).

First, add the following to your POM:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <echo>${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}</echo><!-- I'm a test -->
            <replace file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/myxmlfile.xml" 
                     token="@@@" value="${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}"/> 
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then, update your XML file into:

```
<somenode>
  <fileName>@@@</fileName>
</somenode>
```

With these changes, running `mvn process-resources` would produce the following result:

```
$ cat target/classes/myxmlfile.xml 
<somenode>
  <fileName>OtherLibrary</fileName>
</somenode>
```

Which proves the property is interpolated (but not set during maven filtering of resources)<sup>1</sup>. And if you need to filter more than one file, the [`replace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task can take a fileset. Adapt it to suit your needs.

<sub><sup>1</sup> <strike>Actually, it would be nice to create a new Jira for this bug in the [Maven 2.x Resources Plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES).</strike> I've created [MRESOURCES-118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-118).</sub>

Comment: the interpolation and filtering do not use the same algorithm, so the filtering is only going to have a subset of the expressions

Answer (score 1):

The indexed properties will only be available inside plugin configuration due to the way Maven interpolates the POM - so it is available to antrun's replace task, but not the filtering.

However, accessing dependencies by index is not very robust - it is susceptible to changes in the parent. You might instead use the following in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <fileName>some-name</fileName>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>${fileName}</artifactId>
  ...
</dependency>
```

You can then continue to filter using the property name:

```
<somenode>
  <fileName>${fileName}</fileName>
</somenode>
```

Comment: Actually, I did try what you are suggesting in the first solution when I was writing my answer (and mentioned it in in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-118) but this didn't work, you'll get `<fileName>${project.dependencies[0].artifactId}</fileName>` in the filtered resource. But the second solution is definitely a good one.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that. The interpolation mechanisms are something that has undergone quite a bit of change between Maven 2.0.x, 2.2.x, and 3.0. I believe this expression will only be available inside plugin configuration in most versions of Maven, so it is best not to rely on it at all.

Comment: I should point out that the reason I'm looking for this is what I would guess is a unique situation/edge case where I need to add non EJB jar into my persistence.xml.  And because the ear plugin doesn't have a way to specify the naming convention for jars in the lib folder, I've gone down this path.  The war plugin has a nice way to make jars follow a naming pattern that I wish the ear plugin had.  See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEAR-98 for example.

Eventually I'm going to code the non-ejb jar out of existence.  It's just a jar I inherited and am working to integrate.