# How can you use a dependency from the plugin's dependency scope in the maven-antrun-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

We have a profile that uses `maven-antrun-plugin` to run a downloaded JAR.

**Exhibit A: (this works)**

We can reference the downloaded JAR using the property `${maven.dependency.com.foobar.target-jar.jar.path}` ([Can I use the path to a Maven dependency as a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2359947/1096323)). But in this solution, the custom dependency and repository information isn't limited to just the scope of the profile.

```
<project>
    ...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <name>Third Party</name>
             <url>
                 [URL for the repository that holds the target JAR]
             </url>
             <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foobar</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>runJARprofile</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-jar</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target name="runJar" fork="true">
                                        <java jar="${maven.dependency.com.foobar.target-jar.jar.path}" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
...
</project>
```

**Exhibit B: (haven't gotten it working)**

Here, we moved the dependency and repository information into the profile. Maven downloads the artifact successfully, but we no longer know how to reference it by property.

```
<project>
    ...

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>thirdparty</id>
                    <name>Third Party</name>
                     <url>
                         [URL for the repository that holds the target JAR]
                     </url>
                     <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            ...
            <id>runJARprofile</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.foobar</groupId>
                                <artifactId>target-jar</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-jar</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target name="runJar" fork="true">
                                        <java jar="${?????}" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
...
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem / question.  Where is the property `maven.dependency.com.foobar.target-jar.jar.path` defined in the first place?

Comment: @Tunaki Looks like first example it pulled from the `pom`'s `<dependencies>` with the `${maven.dependency.com.foobar.target-jar.jar.path}`, when the second example wants to use a `<dependency>` that is added to the `<plugin>`. I think the question is "how can you use a dependency from the plugin's dependency scope in the _maven-antrun-plugin_?".

Comment: Based on [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html), the property format `${maven.dependency.com.foobar.target-jar.jar.path}` is deprecated, so we should be using `${com.foobar:target-jar:jar}` instead. Tried this in Exhibit A and it works, but still not working in Exhibit B.

Comment: Why is `Third Party` in **A** within `<repositories>` and in  **B** within `<pluginRepositories>`? Are there still essential parts missing in your question's POM excerpts?

Comment: @GeroldBroser: the `<repositories>` vs `<pluginRepositories>` issue may need a question of its own. In short, for **Exhibit B**, if I replace `<pluginRepositories>` with `<repositories>`, Maven is unable to locate and download `com.foobar.target-jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I crated a POM similar to your **Exhibit B** here and got the following message during a `mvn package -P runJARprofile`:

> ```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run
> (run-jar) on project so-36848518: An Ant BuildException has occured:
> Cannot execute a jar in non-forked mode. Please set fork='true'.
> [ERROR] around Ant part ...<java jar="${my:test:jar}"/>...
> ```

I changed the respective line to:

```
<java jar="${my:test:jar} fork="true"/>
```

and:

> ```
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: Yes, I have the `fork="true"` set in our real project. I was trying to declutter and generalize the examples... shouldn't have removed it without further understanding it. I'll update the original post. Thanks!