# With Maven, how would I prevent Maven from filtering certain properties but allowing others?

Tags: maven-2, ant

The problem is that I'm trying to build a project that has in its resources a build.xml file. Basically, I package my project as a jar with Maven2, and then use ant installer to install my project.

There is a property in the build.xml file that I need to filter called build.date, but there are other properties that I don't want to filter, like ${basedir}, because it's used by the ant installer but gets replaced by Maven's basedir variable. So, I need to somehow tell Maven to filter ${build.date}, but not ${basedir}.

I tried creating a properties file as a filter with "basedir=${basedir}" as one of the properties, but I get the following error:

Resolving expression: '${basedir}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle: [basedir]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

B.J.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible, you can't prevent maven from filtering a given property. So either:

- don't use Maven properties like `${basedir}` in your `build.xml` (if this is possible)
- don't use Maven filtering but use the Maven Antrun Plugin to *replace* the `${build.date}`  and only this property (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246524/how-to-filter-resource-in-maven-replacing-with-a-dependencies-artifactid/2247645#2247645))
- change the [`delimiters`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters) parameter of the resources plugin and use for example `@build.date@` instead of `${build.date}` in your `build.xml`

  ```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
      <delimiters>
       <delimiter>@</delimiter><!-- for Ant-like tokens style -->
      </delimiters>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The 3rd solution was my solution of choice. I had to add <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>

Comment: @Benny Ah yes, forgot about that (I've updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: @Benny BTW, it usually makes sense to [also upvote an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an escape string like e.g.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <escapeString>~~~</escapeString>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then use ~~~${basedir} in your build.xml

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html